# Acces denied when using os.replace()

Tags: python

In my code I want to replace a file to another directory using os.replace(). When I do this, I have the following output:

```
File "CNN.py", line 83, in <module>
    os.replace(NAMES[model], "C:/Users/antho/Bachelorproef/Models")
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Toegang geweigerd: 'C:\\Users\\antho\\Bachelorproef\\tmpo6oj4uh_\\4-conv-128-nodes-2-dense-1585514523' -> 'C:/Users/antho/Bachelorproef/Models
```

Does anyone know how I can resolve this ? I try to move a directory in a temporary directory to the Models directory.

Comment: please try shutil.copyfile(src, dst) command on your problem.

Comment: That gives the same problem:  'File "CNN.py", line 82, in <module>
    shutil.copyfile(NAMES[model], 'C:/Users/antho/Bachelorproef/Models')
  File "C:\Users\antho\anaconda3\envs\tf20\lib\shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:'
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\antho\\Bachelorproef\\tmpttscaxr9\\4-conv-128-nodes-2-dense-1585516563'

Comment: I tried it with the shutil.copytree and it worked ! Thank you !